# Interpretation of Confidence Intervals for Business case

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

In frequentist hypothesis testing for AB tests, when we construct 95% confidence interval around the mean difference between version A and B, the mean is an unbiased estimate between A & B, and we are confident that the confidence interval we construct will capture the true mean 95% of the time if we repeat this method multiple times.

Say we are testing A & B version of website to understand if revenue increased, if confidence interval is between -20,000 and +$200,000, we know that the true mean difference lies between these 2 numbers. Statistically speaking, the difference is not statistically significant, but can we say the upside of the difference (+200K) likely outweigh the downside (we lose 20K) ?

Comment: How would that add to simply reporting the observed mean difference, which presumably is around \$90K, along with the confidence interval or a standard error?

Comment: Can you elaborate? We do report out point estimate and 95% confidence interval.